# C# identifier expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

not sure why this is happening but when I try to wrap my gridview text in a mailto tag I get the Identifier expected error.

```
 if (GVStatus == "Team")
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
                string emailAddy = e.Row.Cells.[8].Text;
                string strEM = "<a href='mailto:"+ emailAddy +"</a>";

                e.Row.Cells.[8].Text = strEM;
                e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

the gridview is all dynamic

Comment: You are missing a closing quote and closing bracket too.  `"'></a>"`

Comment: so looking for an answer nowadays is punishable by downvoting....nice!

Comment: @skullomania everyone learns. Some people have too much fun downvoting others, hopefully the admins implement a function that will make people explain why they downvoted, or best case scenario answer the question if you downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your errors are in those lines:

```
string emailAddy = e.Row.Cells.[8].Text;
e.Row.Cells.[8].Text = strEM;
```

Remove extra `.` and it will work:

```
string emailAddy = e.Row.Cells[8].Text;
e.Row.Cells[8].Text = strEM;
```

As a side note you're also creating incorrect HTML, it should be:

```
string strEM = "<a href='mailto:"+ emailAddy +"'></a>";
```

Comment: also might wanna fix that missing '> tag on the opening a href element created in strings

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how correct Html should look like.

Answer (score 2):

You have a stray `.` in your statement. Should be:

```
e.Row.Cells[8].Text = strEM;
```

Also, as walkhard suggested, you need to fix your `HTML` statement:

```
string strEM = "<a href='mailto:"+ emailAddy +"'></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your quote in the href:

```
string strEM = "<a href='mailto:"+ emailAddy +"'</a>";
```

Actually, the entire anchor is malformed.

```
string strEM = "<a href='mailto:"+ emailAddy + "'></a>";
```